# pycharm не видит types в библиотеке telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Саму библиотеку telebot он видит а модуль types нет. Скорее всего из-за  обновления python 3.8.4 до 3.9, но информацию по этому поводу не смог найти.

Comment: from telebot import types?

Comment: @Данилкин именно

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=from+telebot+import+types+doesn%27t+see&oq=from+telebot+import+types+doesn%27t+see&aqs=chrome..69i57.6986j1j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было всего лишь скачать библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI